# Create an empty Footer UICollectionReusableCell

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a UICollectionReusableView However it should only be shown if following conditions is met and if not it should return an empty or nothing. How can i do this? i've tried below, but im retrieving following error:

`'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath (UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter,<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: or is nil`

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {


    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {

        if self.moreDataAvailable == true {




           let footerView : UICollectionReusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "ActivityReusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)





            return footerView
        } else {
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        }

    } else {
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }

}
```

**tried changing frame**

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {


    let footerView : UICollectionReusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "ActivityReusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        if self.moreDataAvailable == true {



            return footerView
        } else {

            footerView.frame = CGRectZero

            return footerView
        }



}
```

Comment: You can set frame or opacity of 'footerView' according to condition meet.. suppose you want to empty footerview  then you can set frame like footerview.frame = CGRectZero

Comment: i've tried that, but there still seem to be a empty space below the cells...

Comment: i've added what i've tried with frame

Comment: Did you still get same error message?

Comment: You can set sectionInset to avoid the space :
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
        collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: I've allready done that

Answer (score 0):

The immediate cause of the exception must be this:

```
    return UICollectionReusableView()
```

You can't just create one like this, you must use dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind.

My suggestion is to define a reusable cell, in the same manner that you defined ActivityReusableCell. Give it a height of zero, create it using dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind, and return it.